# Updating JList data

Tags: java, variables, frame, jlist

greetings

I'm having problems to update a JList, the numerical values ​​that are in the JList are variables of other classes, and I would like that when I alter the value of these variables in other classes, and pressed the button "Refresh" in class FrameTeste the data in the JList would be updated according to the changes I made in the other classes, I created an example of two different classes of variables with different values ​​and a class that is the frame, it has a JList and button "Refresh",

Exemple :

[image]

[image]

And the Frame Class :

[image]

when I change the value of variables that belong to OtherClass1 and OtherClass2 and press the refresh button in the Frame class, I would like the values ​​to be updated JList, I've tried everything, but without success. Thank you guys.

Comment: Your post doesn't contain near enough information to allow folks to guess what you might be doing wrong, other than declaring your variables public when the should be private. You will want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to have the best chances of getting decent quick help.

Comment: The easy option is to instantiate a new JList and replace the existing one. The other options is to play with [AbstractListModel#fireContentsChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), which allows you to reuse the same list.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement ListModel for JList.

```
 DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
 JList list = new JList( listModel );


// On Press on refresh button       
             if( Refresh Event is Triggered){
                List<String> freshData= getFreshData();

                // Remove all elemets of Jlist
                listModel.removeAllElements(); 

                    // Add new contents to list
                for(String data:freshData){
                    listModel.addElement(data);
                }
```

Hope this answers your concern.

Comment: My friend,I am very grateful for the example you gave me, I really enjoyed, thank you, but I have only one question, how should I implement the method getFreshData ()? What should I declare this method? What this method should return? It is the only part of your example I do not understand, how I should handle this method getFreshData () '.Can you give me a simple example about this method? How to implement what he should return, and where it should be implemented? I need to import some classes, but I wonder what are the correct, just to be sure and do everything right. Thank you my friend!

Comment: My regrets, that i could not reply you early.  getFreshData() can be any method, specially in your case it might be method that gets called on click of refresh button. That is the method that fetches updated contents from db.